# Trouble Installing Standard ML

Tags: macos, sml, smlnj

So I'm trying to install Standard ML/NJ on a Mac running Yosemite.  I download the installer for Mac OS X PPC and try to install.  I get an error saying

"The installation failed.  The installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail.  Contact the software manufacturer for assistance."

So I googled around and found this workaround:

http://users-cs.au.dk/danvy/dIFP09/smlnj/Mac-OS-X-Snow-Leopard-install-smlnj.txt

I can't seem to access my /usr folder though.  Any recs?

Thanks for the help,
bclayman

Comment: Are you sure you need the PPC binary? Try this download link: http://smlnj.cs.uchicago.edu/dist/working/110.78/smlnj-x86-110.78.pkg Another option might be to install Homebrew, and then install SML/NJ from Homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

The installer did not worked for me either.

What I did was

1. Install Homebrew on OSX.
2. Open terminal and enter

**`brew install smlnj`**

Hope this helps everybody.

Ref: http://brewformulas.org/Smlnj